# C# float variables are losing their decimals after being inserted on mysql database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, windows-server

I've got a really weird problem here !

I've written a `C#` console app to get data from predefined IP addresses, after the calculations, I want the data to be inserted to a `MySQL` database so I can read it and do more calculations if needed using a `PHP` web application,

on my lap top everything is working perfectly,

when I run the `C#` app on the server, the data is being handled perfectly until the last step which is inserting it, but when it inserts the data, it's like an integer, no decimals.

I used VS Studio tools and tracked my variables, they are correct even in the `sql` statements but on the database they're losing their decimals.

I'm using windows 10 on my laptop and the server has windows Server 2016

here's the `C#` code :

```
public static string send_to_db(int uid, float prs, float btlvl, float f1, float f2, double t1, double t2, int dState, int supState, string datetime, string stmt)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        string feedback = "";
        double min_prs_val = 0, max_prs_val = 0;

        // voltage to percentage the btlvl

        btlvl = (btlvl * 100) / 12;

        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(stmt);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand insertData = new MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO pm_data_records (pm_detail_id, pm_pressure, pm_battery_charge, pm_flow1, pm_flow2, pm_tot1, pm_tot2, pm_door, pm_sup, pm_sent_time) VALUES('{uid}','{prs}','{btlvl}','{f1}','{f2}','{t1}','{t2}','{dState}','{supState}','{datetime}')", connection);
            insertData.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlCommand updateData = new MySqlCommand($"UPDATE pm_data_last SET pm_detail_id = '{uid}', pm_pressure = '{prs}', pm_battery_charge = '{btlvl}', pm_flow1 = '{f1}', pm_flow2 = '{f2}', pm_tot1 = '{t1}', pm_tot2 = '{t2}', pm_door = '{dState}', pm_sup = '{supState}', pm_sent_time = '{datetime}' WHERE pm_detail_id = '{uid}'", connection);
            updateData.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ...
```

I installed visual studio on the server and copied the code from my laptop and compiled it there too (after installing the `MySQL` for vs files) and still no decimals,

I'm outta ideas, help me plz ! tnx

Comment: which data type is the related  column in db ?

Comment: floats and doubles ... all of the are losing their decimals just on the server ! not  my laptop ! :(

Comment: Why do you do string interpolation instead of parametrized queries? You open yourself to all kind of dangerous or weird things: from SQL injections to culture dependent string representation (decimal separator).

Comment: @PetSerAl would it make any difference in this case ?! I aint a pro in `C#` programming but I dont think that's the problem here , as i explained the variables are correct even in the `sql` statement .
plus this program isn't on the internet so everybody can try to hack into it, it's using specific apn and a totally different IP range

Comment: @arian.s Are you absolutely sure that values in SQL query is indeed correct, e.g. they are `'1.2345'` but not `'1,2345'`?

Comment: @PetSerAl yes I'm absolutely sure tnx to visual studio, I traced my variables and all their values are correct even in the sql statement, as i explained everything is perfectly working on my laptop! It's just not working as good on the server!

Comment: I see only two possibility: 1) executing the same query produce different result depending on which client initiate the query (honestly, I do not see how is that possible in your case); 2) different clients generate different queries for the same input data, thus getting different result. You should check which of this happens in your case.

Comment: @PetSerAl : I found the problem ! It was actually the number format from windows options. the format was Persian  in which there's no " . " !! it's " / " instead. any way tnx for the help :))

Answer (score 1):

1. You should never build query strings with parameters using the string interpolation like this.

   - This is security issue;
   - Your values may not be properly formatted and escaped. So maybe the problem is there actually.

You should do something like this:

```
using (var command = new MySqlCommand('INSERT INTO pm_data_records (pm_detail_id, pm_pressure, pm_battery_charge, pm_flow1, pm_flow2, pm_tot1, pm_tot2, pm_door, pm_sup, pm_sent_time) VALUES (@uid, @prs, @btlvl, @f1, @f2, @t1, @t2, @dState, @supState, @datetime)', connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uid);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prs", prs);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@btlvl", btlvl);
    ...
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

2. Check data types of columns in your database. Maybe they do not allow floating-point numbers.

Comment: tnx for the answer, I tested this code but unfortunately the problem's not solved yet, I'm still loosing the decimals on my database :(